# How do I change the size and appearance of the suggestions box of the jQuery UI autocomplete control?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

I've been reading and I feel lost. I am using a jQuery UI autocomplete widget to provide suggestions and it works alright. Only it appears strange (see picture below) and I want it to appear like I want.

[image]

The two things I want to change are:

1. Its position so that it is as wide as the text box that it is serving. And
2. Its font-size.

Here is my thinking so far.

**Position**

I looked up the [`position` `option`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-position) of the autocomplete widget in the documentation, and also the documentation of the [`UI.position()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) plug-in.

And I thought, "I want the suggestion box's "left top" to align with the "left top" of the `txtCategory` textbox," so I said:

```
$("#txtCategory").autocomplete({
    source: articleCategories, // that's an array I made
    position: {
        my: "left top",
        at: "left top",
        of: "#txtCategory",
        collision: "fit"
    }
});
```

But I suspect that that won't work, because I don't how to tell it that I also want its "right bottom" to align with the "right bottom" of the textbox. So it looks even more bizarre now (see picture below).

[image]

How do I position it so it is as wide as the textbox `txtCategory` and, say, about 4 entries tall?

**Appearance**

To change the appearance, I am reading through the [CSS Framework documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/) for theming jQuery UI but I a not sure which *structural class* should be applied to control the suggestion box container.

So, I tried all the three, the `ui-widget` class, the `ui-widget-content` class and the `ui-menu` class from the [`Menu` documentation page](https://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#theming) for [theming the autocomplete menu](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), like so, one by one, and none of them changed anything.

```
.suggestionBox {
    background-color: red;
}



$("#txtCategory").autocomplete({

    ... // other options

    classes: {
        "ui-widget": "suggestionBox"
        // "ui-widget-container": "suggestionBox"
        // "ui-menu": "suggestionBox"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of painful debugging, I found the answer to all of my questions. Some of them might be embarrassingly obvious but since I made the mistake, I guess many others might.

**Make sure you download jQuery UI correctly**

I had copied just the following script tag in my HTML page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

That's not enough. jQuery UI comes with some CSS files if you want to apply themes. Also, what controls go in into the jQuery JavaScript file you will download can be configured, just like Bootstrap.

Silly me, and sill you, we'd have done this so many times over the past but forgotten. So, go to the [Downloads page](https://jqueryui.com/download/) and check the check-boxes for whatever controls you want to play with, and at the bottom of the page, select the theme you want. Then, click **Download**.

As of today, that should give you the following that you will need to move to your projects folder hierarchy wherever you like:

1. jquery-ui.min.js (and an unminified JavaScript file for you to read)
2. jquery-ui.structure.min.css (and an unminified CSS file)
3. jquery-ui.theme.min.css (and unminified): this is required for applying themes. Here is where all the classes such as `ui-autocomplete` and `ui-menu` of the jQuery UI CSS Framework reside.
4. jquery-ui.css
5. images: This folder is required for jQuery UI to display images for bullet points and the like. Copy it into the folder where you place your jQueryUI CSS files.
6. external: A folder that contains jquery. Since jQuery UI is based on jQuery, you need jquery in your project. If you've already got the jQuery file referenced in your project, then you do not need this folder.

**Get the `position` right**

With the set up I had, I was telling it to align the top-left of the suggestion box to the top-left of the control `#txtCategory`. So the result would be like so:

[image]

I needed to change that to display the top-left of the suggestion box at the *bottom-left* of the `#txtCategory` control, like so:

```
var autoComplete = $("#txtCategory").autocomplete({
    
    ...
    
    position: {
        my: "left top",
        at: "left bottom", // changed from "left top"
        of: "#txtCategory",
        collision: "fit" // this takes care of the width
    }
    
    ...
});
```

So, it would look nice like so:

[image]

**Changing appearance**

For almost 4 hours yesterday, nothing worked. I tried removing the `classes` object declaration from the control initializer and tried specifying it later using the following but none of them seemed to change the look.

```
var autoComplete = $("#txtCategory").autocomplete( {
...
};

// This did not work either
autoComplete.autocomplete("option", "classes.ui-autoComplete", "myCustomClass");

// And neither did this
autoComplete.option("classes.ui-autocomplete", "myCustomClass");
```

I then tried setting the `css` via jQuery itself but that didn't work either.

```
// Did not work
autoComplete.css("font-size", "1.4rem");

// Neither did this
autoComplete.css( {
  "font-size": "1.4rem", 
  ... // other CSS rule declarations
});
```

Of course, those won't work because we are specifying these declarations in the `document.ready` method of jQuery, which happens when the document is loaded. However, the suggestion box is added dynamically *much later*. Therefore, it would have made sense to have these declarations be added *as soon as the dynamic content, that is, the suggestion box, was added* to the document. However, *we* are not adding the suggestion box. JQuery UI is.

Just to make sure that this feature wasn't incomplete, I tried isolating just this bit of code to make an autocomplete into a separate example and its CSS worked.

So, after a lot more of painful debugging, here is what helped.

1. Restart Visual Studio

   I had my Visual Studio session going on from yesterday. Apparently, Visual Studio caches some stuff. I can only surmise this without any solidarity because when I inspected my CSS classes that applied to the suggestion box elements, my own `customClass` did not even appear in the **Rules** section.

[image]

After I restarted Visual Studio, my class started appearing in the element's rule set. This was a relief. However, the element still did not apply my definition of my custom class named `override-autocomplete`.

[image]

2. Make sure that your own CSS file declaration appears *after* the jQuery UI CSS files

   I changed the order of my CSS declarations so that my own CSS file declaration appeared *after* the jQuery UI one, and it all worked.

   And the thing started working.

[image]